# How to use an abstract class's property?

Tags: c#, properties, abstract

The property is inside an abstract class and then called from main. The goal is to print "Bip bip Digital" but it only prints "Bip bip". I even tried setting the _phoneType variable with a constructor and it doesn't work either.

```
using System;
abstract class Telephone
{
    protected string _phoneType;
    public string PhoneType {
        set
        {
            _phoneType = PhoneType;
        }
        get
        {
            return _phoneType;
        }
    }
    public abstract void Ring();
}
class DigitalPhone : Telephone
{
    public override void Ring()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bip bip {0}", _phoneType);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DigitalPhone myDPhone = new DigitalPhone();
        myDPhone.PhoneType = "Digital";
        myDPhone.Ring();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `PhoneType` setter should be `_phoneType = value;` Your implementation currently just sets it to the existing value, which is null.

Comment: @MethodMan: No, there's no need for that.

Comment: @Lee nice catch! Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PhoneType` setter currently just sets `_phoneType` to its current value, which is null initially. You should change it to:

```
set
{
    _phoneType = value;
}
```

or simply use an auto-property:

```
public string PhoneType { get; set; }
```

Comment: I spent hours with this I can't believe I made such a terrible mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the setter, it is not setting the passed in value to _phoneType. Easy mistake to make. It should be...

```
set
{
    _phoneType = value;
}
```

Otherwise the code all looks fine to me.